# How to reset ngx-treeview

Tags: angular, treeview

I'm using plug ngx tree view version 1.2.5 for tree view I need to reset the tree view or unchecked the all selected tree items
I tried to do it by moving initial data to the item variable

Comment: <ngx-treeview [config]="config" [items]="items" (selectedChange)="onSelectedChange($event) (filterChange)="onFilterChange($event)"></ngx-treeview>

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this code to check/uncheck all items:

```
itemsChecked(boolChecked: boolean) {
    this.trvComponent.items.forEach(element => {
    element.checked = boolChecked;
    element.children.forEach(elem => {
        elem.checked = boolChecked;
    });
 });
}
```

Note: this is for a 2 level treeview. if you have more than 2 levels change the code.

Before using this code add a ViewChild decleration to Export Class section like this:

```
@ViewChild(TreeviewComponent, { static: true }) trvComponent: TreeviewComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can lever the [onAllCheckedChange()](https://github.com/leovo2708/ngx-treeview/blob/master/projects/ngx-treeview/src/lib/components/treeview/treeview.component.ts#L105) api. You just need to programmatically uncheck the 'All' selector.

```
// get a reference to the TreeViewComponent
@ViewChild(TreeViewComponent, {Static: true}) tree: TreeViewComponent;

// reset the 'All' checked flag
// and trigger the change handler
resetSelection() {
    this.tree.allItem.checked = false; 
    this.tree.onAllCheckedChange();  
}
```